# How to return a string from an array

Tags: python, encryption

```
    keyword = raw_input ("Enter your keyword") *10000
keyword = keyword.lower()
keywordoutput = []
for character in keyword:
    number = ord(character) 
    keywordoutput.append(number)


input1 = raw_input('Write Text: ')
input1 = input1.lower()
output1 = []
for character in input1:
    number = ord(character)
    output1.append(number)


output2 = [x + y for x, y in zip(output1, keywordoutput)]
print output2
```

That is my code so far. I am trying to create a program that uses a simple Vigenere Cypher to encrypt an inputted text. The code works perfectly, yet I am having an issue implimenting new code to return a string of 'output2'.

I get 'output2' easily, but from there i need to make it a simple string.
Eg: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 becomes (1234)

I have tried, but I cant seem to implement such a thing into my code.

Comment: It works fine and giving output as expected. What's the problem ?

Comment: Do you mean `print ''.join(map(str, output2))`?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert numbers into text.

```
output2 = map(str, output2)
```

Then you can use `join` to concatenate elements.

```
print "".join(output2)
```

Or in one line:

```
print "".join(map(str, output2))
```

Answer (score 0):

**One step** use -> `join`:

```
output2 = ''.join([str(x + y) for x, y in zip(output1, keywordoutput)])
```

Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join

As the function is expecting a `string` type you must covert the numeric result `x + y`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
print ''.join(str(i) for i in output2)
```